# Javascript: Get domain in iframe

Tags: javascript, search, dns

Is it possible for me to get the domain from an iframe for example like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/search&etc...so on"></iframe>
```

So by using javascript, i could get only "google.com" and redirect the iframe to blank. Below is idea (in python coding, idk if it correct or not, but just an idea) for anyone wishes to help me.

```
for iframe in page:
if re.search("(google.com)", iframe, re.IGNORECASE):
iframe = iframe.replace('<iframe src=""></iframe>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('IFRAME');
for (var iFrameIndex = 0; iFrameIndex < iFrames.length; iFrameIndex++) {
    // Match Google iFrames
    if (iFrames[iFrameIndex].src.test(/google\.com/)) {
        // Set such iFrames src to a blank string
        iFrames[iFrameIndex].src = '';
    }
}
```

​
Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/nZyyB/)

Answer (score 0):

You could search for all iframes in your page and then get the ones that have google.com as source :

```
var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME");
for (var i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
    if (iFrames[i].src.indexOf("google.com") != -1) {
        // do here whatever you want, for example clearing the iframe's src:
        iFrames[i].src = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer pertains to JavaScript, as per your tagging.  Yes, it's possible to get the domain.  However there is a very important rule.  If the iframe is 1) a different domain than the parent page **AND** 2) the iframe changes to a different page/domain after the first load... then you can't see the new page/domain.

Lets say you have an index.html page on `yourdomain.com` and you want to have an iframe which loads Google:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div><iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When your index page first loads, you will be able to see that the domain is google.com.  However, if a user performs a Google search, you will not be able to see the new URL.  This is a security feature of browsers where you cannot see any activity of an external domain within an iframe.  Furthermore, if a person clicks on a Google search result to even another domain, you cannot see the new domain.  The URL will always appear to be http://www.google.com.  Hope that helps.

I see others have already posted examples... but thought I'd put a jQuery example because it might help somebody out there:

```
$('iframe[src*="google.com"').attr('src', '');
```